# CakePHP 2 and jQuery don't show results in DIV

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm trying to make auto refresh DIV with updated data. It seems to be ok but it doesn't show any results on webpage.

Thanks for help :)

Controller:

```
public function homeNewMessagesAjax() {
            $this->disableCache();

            $options = array('conditions' => array('Message.is_read' => '0'));
            $messages = $this->Message->find('count', $options);

            $this->set(compact('messages'));

    }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
        var targetUrl = "/Messages/homeNewMessagesAjax.json";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: targetUrl,
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.content){
                    $("#headerMessages").html(response.content);
                }
            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    }, 10000);
}
```

JSON view:

```
if ($messages > 0) {
    //some info
} else {
    //some info
}
```

View with destination DIV:

```
echo "<div id=\"headerMessages\">";

echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some similar thing a few days ago. The following works for me:

**Controller:**

```
public function admin_add() {
    $this->request->onlyAllow('ajax');

    // some controller logic ...

    $task = $this->Task->findById( $this->Task->id );
    $this->set(compact('task'));
    $this->set('_serialize', array('task')); // generates json response without the need of a view file
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('form#TaskAdminIndexForm').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var targeturl = '/admin/tasks/add.json';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: targeturl,
        data:$('form').serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        },
        success: function(response) {
            var task = response.task.Task;
            $("#tasjTitle").html(task.name);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert("An error occurred: " + e.responseText.message);
            console.log(e);
        }
    });   
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've made some changes in my code: added `$this->set('_serialize', array('messages'));` in controller and `$("#headerMessages").html(response.messages);` in JS. This give me just simple number of new messages (as I want) but I don't know how to manipulate the response in php and html (e.g. add some if and css, link). Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: The `response.massages` should give you a JSON object of your messages.

Comment: So you can do something like `if(response.messages.lenght < 1) { $('#headerMessages').addClass('empty'); $('#headerMessages.empty').html('No messages');} else { $.each(response.messages, function(message) { $('#headerMessages').append('<h2>'+message.name+'</h2>');});}`